# HTML Select only added to last row

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

### INTRO

I am trying to add a select box to a `<td>`-cell. I have no idea how many rows or `<td>`'s there will be and no idea how many options there will be in the select box, so I need to do this dynamically.

### MY CODE

I first build my `<select>` box like so:

```
var select = $("<select>").addClass('form-control');
// for later expansion, as user can add custom fields
var options = {
    ''                  : 'Ignore',
    'first_name'        : 'First Name',
    'last_name'         : 'Last Name',
    'full_name'         : 'Full Name',
    'email'             : 'Email',
    'cellphone_number'  : 'Cellphone Number'
};
$.each(options,function(i,v) {
    select.append($('<option>').val(i).text(v));
});
```

Then I add it like so:

```
$.each(parsedCSV[0],function(i,v) {
    value = [];
    if(i != "") {
        for(k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            value.push(parsedCSV[k][i]);
        }
        tr = $('<tr>').appendTo(table);
        if(col_header) {
            tr.append($('<tr>').html(i));
        }
        tr.append($('<td>')
            .append(select)
        ).append($('<td>')
            .html(value.join(', '))
        );
    }
});
```

`parsedCSV` is an `Object` that looks like this:

```
{
    'name' : 'value',
    'index' : 'value',
    'foo' : 'bar',
}
```

This `Object` can have any number of keys and values.

### WHAT'S WRONG?

The `<select>` box only ever appears in the last row and not in every row how I'd like it to. If I add a `console.log(select)` in the `$.each()` it shows in the console of chrome so it's there.

Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An element can't exist in multiple places in the DOM at once.

When you append it somewhere, it is removed from the DOM if it is there already and placed in the new location.

You only create one select element, and then you try to put it in multiple places.

Either:

- Call the code which creates it multiple times *or*
- Clone the first one you create each time you append it

Comment: Thanks. Love this answer because firstly you explain the problem, and secondly provide a solution (in this case two) to the problem.